# ERROR: User is not a constructor -- node js with express , sequelize, postgresSQL

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I am making login app with node.js(sequalize,express) and postgresql db, while inserting data i am geting ERROR:TypeError: User is not a constructor

//users/user.model.js

```
module.exports = (sequelize, type)=> {
    return sequelize.define('user', {
        id: {
            type: type.INTEGER,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true
          },
        username:  type.STRING,
        hash: type.STRING,
        firstName: type.STRING,
        lastName: type.STRING,
    },{ freezeTableName: true })
}
```

//_helper/db.js

```
const config = require('config.json');
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const UserModel = require('../users/user.model');

//const sequelize = new Sequelize('postgres://user:pass@example.com:5432/dbname');
//var sequelize = new Sequelize(config.database, config.username, config.password);
const sequelize = new Sequelize(config.connectionString1);
const User = UserModel(sequelize, Sequelize)

module.exports = {
  User
}
```

//users/user.service.js

```
const { User } = require('../_helpers/db');
sync function create(userParam) {
    const user = new User(userParam);

    // save user
    await user.save();
}
```

After calling save() method in user.service i am getting the error.

Comment: `module.exports = User` I guess.

Comment: @TGrif not  working with module.exports = User

Answer (score 0):

```
const user = await User.create(userParam); no need `new` operate
```